# Computer generated/aided glossing

Tags: machine-translation, tools, interlinear-gloss

I want to experiment with innovative ways of presenting a written text on a printed page to help a non-native speaker to read it. The example I have in mind is the Iliad for people whose native language is English. For this purpose, it would help if I had a way of automatically generating semi-reliable glosses. These might have to be human-corrected, but it would be really nice to have a relatively low error rate on the software-generated glosses.

As an example, the verb ἐρύω has meanings (1) to drag, and (2) to protect or guard. Both of these meanings occur in Homer. There is open-source software called CLTK that can in most cases accurately look at an inflected Greek word and detect the lexical form. So let's say that I write a script that can take a line of Homer and automatically detect that a certain word is a form of ἐρύω. Then let's say I have a digitized dictionary that contains the relevant information, that

ἐρύω => ["drag","protect","guard"].

Project Gutenberg has about a half-dozen English translations of Homer, so a pretty simple algorithm would be just to figure out which one-sentence snippets in the English translations correspond to this fragment of Homer, and look for words like "drag," "drags," "protecting," "guarded," etc. If the software finds that several of the translations include the string "guarded," then we offer this as a gloss.

Is this a problem that has been previously tackled? Am I reinventing the wheel? Is this a bad idea and doomed to failure?

Comment: Here's something like what you want to make: Qur'an with each verse in Arabic (on the right) translated to English (on the left), it shows the translation of each Arabic word when hovering the cursor over the word and pronounces the Arabic word when you click the word: https://quran.com/1

Comment: @YellowSky: That's pretty nice. My idea was for a format to be used on a literal printed page, but anyway that's not what my SE question is directly about.

Comment: I think this is a lot of the intended purpose that SIL's [Fieldworks](https://software.sil.org/fieldworks/) was designed for.

Comment: Interesting question and project. +1 for the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you are looking for a word-by-word approach to the text. This is often done in corpus linguistics when you build a new corpus: Start with word forms, add lemma and part of speech and morphological analysis.

The critical task comes now, it is called **word sense disambiguation** and disentangles the different potential meanings of one word. There are automated tools in computational linguistics for this task, but I don't know whether there is something ready to handle Ancient Greek.

Answer (score 1):

In machine translation, the task you're describing is known as **word alignment**.

(In the days of statistical machine translation, it was inherent to the task.  Now, with machine translation, the main use is for preserving XML tags.)

The rules-based dictionary-based approach you describe is not used and is out of fashion.  It may well be a good fit for your domain and application.

The common statistical or neural approaches neither require nor provide explicit information about the part of speech or surface form.  There are two possible approaches, depending on the scenario:

- learn and generate alignments along with machine translation, given only the source sentence
- generate alignments, given the source sentence and the translation

For options, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905945/find-phrase-word-equivalent-in-translated-sentence/66908397#66908397

The Microsoft Translator API does not support Ancient Greek.

Answer (score -2):

This is well within the capabilities of contemporary NLP and AI / LLM’s. As of writing this, some options to disambiguate a word and provide translation in context could include any standard machine translation software framework such as OpenNMT and any NLP library such as Spacy, which has a lemmatization capability. Beyond that, modern AI like ChatGPT is extremely good at this stuff.

Comment: I'd definitely not use ChatGPT for creating interlinear glosses, because it has a tendency to cheat.

Comment: I think my answer can be justified if I add in a little detail. I think to generate accurate glosses you might be able to develop a context-sensitive rule-based solution if you had very good dictionary-type data and maybe some kind of n-gram type context checker. But this is the kind of problem that shows how useful machine learning has been for NLP. You could use/make a translation engine, and then try to align the words. One theoretical problem might be when an idiomatic translation barely lines up with the original. I feel pretty confident a general-pretrained transformer would be both the

Comment: simplest implementation from a programming perspective as well as the most effective. It comes closest to having the "general intelligence" necessary to solve the problem that mirrors the nature of the problem itself, not an attempt to fit a phenomenon into a rule-set that in reality it doesn't actually abide by. I can try to follow up soon showing that I think that transformers might overall be best at this task. (It's just a current opinion, can't be certain at all, of course.)

Comment: You can edit your answer when you think that you can improve on it, and this is actually the encouraged way to deal with an answer that attracts some downvotes.